# What does "$A^b \bmod c$, where $A$ is a square matrix" mean? What is the modulus of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

I was reading Wikipedia's ["Modular exponentiation" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). It made sense to me until I got to the part about [Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Matrices).

What does "$A^b \bmod c$, where $A$ is a square matrix" mean? What is the modulus of a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means to consider every element of $A^b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_c$, a.k.a. to take $\mod c$ over every term of the resulting $A^b$. This way, $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}_c$, and $A^b \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}_c$. Note that $b$ has to be an integer.

I recommend checking this previous question to see why this is consistent: [Modular Arithmetic over a Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198919/modular-arithmetic-over-a-matrix)

Comment: So $A$ should have integer entries, and $b$ should be a nonnegative integer.  Then $A^b$ has integer entries, all of which should be reduced mod $c$.